# Node Winston logs partial data

Tags: node.js, winston

I just updated `winston` from version 2.4.4 to 3.1.2. Previously it worked god but now it logs only certain part of message.

i have lots of logs made life that:

```
logger.log("Operation 1", param1, param2, param3)
logger.error("Error 1", err, param1, param2)
```

in the old version the params where logged but in the newest one only the forst string is logged... is there a way to log all the data?

I attach my config

```
const fileTransport = new winston.transports.File({
        timestamp: () => moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss:SSS'),
        filename: process.env.LOG_FILE,
        format: winston.format.json(),
        prettyPrint: true,
        maxsize: 5e+6,
    })

const consoleTransport = new winston.transports.Console({
    timestamp: () => moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss:SSS'),
    colorize: true,
    format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.prettyPrint(),
    winston.format( (info, opts) => {
      console.log(info)

      return `${info.timestamp} - ${info.level}: ${info.message} ${_.join(info.splat, ',')}`
    })
  ),
  })
```

Thank you!

Comment: winston 2x is fundamentally different to winston 3.x. If you don't want to change your code, stick with 2x. If you are willing to, check out the parts about `splat` in the [winston documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Comment: Replace `info.splat` with `info[Symbol.for('splat')]`.